# How to undo C-s C-x in ViM?

Tags: vim, emacs, vi

Sometimes I forget that I am in ViM, and I press C-s C-x, which is Save and Exit in Emacs.

This had the effect in ViM, that it writes `^X` and freezes.

Does anyone know how to either undo or return to ViM in such a situation, so I can save the changes?

Comment: `C-s` starts interactive search in Emacs. It is interrupted by `C-x` which is a prefix. You probably use a non-standard key bindings in Emacs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C-s sends a stop signal to your terminal, if not configured differently. To "unstop", use C-q.See [this entry in the novice bash tips](http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue14/bashtip.html) manual.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>CTRL + q</kbd>. in a console <kbd>CTRL s</kbd> is scroll lock, resume is <kbd>CTRL + q</kbd>.